# GPO to disable/hide language selection on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, language, group-policy

Is there a group policy to hide the language selection on the Windows XP taskbar? I need to set this on several machines so don't want to go hiding it one by one.

[image: Language selection]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following registry setting to remove it:

```
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{540D8A8B-1C3F-4E32-8132-530F6A502090}]
@="Language bar"
"MenuTextPUI"="@%SystemRoot%\\System32\\msutb.dll,-325"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
NoSaveSettings"=dword:00000000
```

Once you've done that, you can create an Administrative Template from it and deploy that (instructions in [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816662) knowledgebase article).

Comment: Thanks. Your post has a few typos (one missing "\" after CLSID and a space between msutb. and dll) so it didn't work out of the box, but here's the corrected version that does work:
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{540D8A8B-1C3F-4E32-8132-530F6A502090}]
@="Language bar"
"MenuTextPUI"="@%SystemRoot%\\System32\\msutb.dll,-325"